# Access Denied for someuser@localhost (Using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, xampp

I'm in the process of learning PHP and MYSQL. I created a new user with the privileges select, insert, update, delete, create, alter, index, and drop and they are database specific. When I try to have this user log in I keep getting

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bookorama'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

I can log in as root user and I'm not sure what I need to do to be able to let this user use the database. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This error means that you are using incorrect password.

Comment: I've changed the password for this user many times and made sure to use the correct one. I don't believe that's the reason.

Comment: This FAQ might help you: http://www.webyog.com/faq/content/23/18/en/error-no-1045-connection-denied.html

Comment: @ManikBaasha Thank you for that FAQ but I tried all the things it recommended and I'm still not getting it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case that you've executed the GRANT command correctly, execute the command "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" and try again.

If it fails again you'll have to check your GRANT command: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

An example:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename.* TO 'bookorama'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```